# "Bringing ambition in/to life."

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

What is difference between below mentioned sentences.

1. Bringing ambition in life.
2. Bringing ambition to life.

Comment: They aren't complete sentences, but phrases. What context will they be used in?

Comment: [the sentences mentioned below]

Answer (score 1):

They aren't complete sentences, but phrases. A verb ending in -ing is either a present participle or a gerund. If this is a gerund (which is a noun), then the phase contains a noun (bringing) and a preposition (in life). However, sentences in English should have a subject and verb: "She walks". "He drives".   Subject - Verb.

Continuing on, it is not entirely clear what you mean.  Perhaps you are trying to say:

"Be ambitious!"
"Be more ambitious!"
"You need to be more ambitious to succeed in life."
"Why don't you have any ambition?"

The word "ambition" is an abstract concept. It's not a physical object. You can't always, necessarily "bring" an abstract idea. You can "bring a book". You can "bring a towel". However, you cannot, for example "bring happiness" with you on a vacation.

Unless it's *poetry*, where everything is permitted.

So, for the abstract idea of "ambition", the most common verbs are "have (ambition)", and "be (ambitious)".

What about the sentence -

"You need to bring more ambition into your life."

While this might be understandable, I believe it sounds awkward and unusual.

The preposition "into" is probably preferable here, compared to either "in" or "to."

Finally, just for your information, the set phrase "bring to life" has a special meaning - a meaning which is *different* from "bring something into someone's life."

From https://www.wordreference.com/synonyms/bring%20to%20life

"bring to life" WordReference English Thesaurus © 2021
Synonyms: inspirit, activate, liven, enliven, animate, excite, make lifelike, breathe life into, put new life into, rouse